# Macro to do random allocation for audit purposes

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me to create a macro based on the below requirements?

On daily basis I will receive an production file from the production team, the production numbers may change based on the inventory.

Total employees: 300 and they produce 5000 records means I need to pick rows randomly based on the % which.

For example, if I am receiving the production file which contain 5000 rows means I need to allocate certain 50% or 60% or 70%  for doing an random audit. (% also vary  based on the number of auditors). That random pick should cover all the employees present on that.

Comment: This is super easy to do without VBA.  ***1.*** Add a column.  ***2.*** Fill all the cells with `=RAND()`. ***3.*** Copy the column and paste it back as values. ***4.*** Filter for numbers below .5, .6, or .7 based on your percentage.

Comment: Thanks for your swift assistance....

Comment: Where does I need to enter the %

Comment: Nowhere. =RAND returns a decimal between 0 and 1. The you filter for numbers above and below your threshold.

Comment: Thanks  boss...I will compute and let you know if I face any issue

Comment: See the answer by @Gary'sStudent too - it's essentially the same.  It uses a sort and row count (which is slightly more accurate - the filter relies on the assumption that the RAND function will have a truly random distribution).

Answer (score 3):

Say the 5000 records are on a *Data* worksheet.  On a separate worksheet called *Picks*, fill **A1** through **A5000** with 1 through 5000.  Fill **B1** through **B5000** with the function:

```
=RAND()
```

Then sort cols **A** and **B** by **B**:

[image]

Now you have a list of the random picks.

1. for 50% use rows 1 through 2500
2. for 60% use rows 1 through 3000
3. for 70% use rows 1 through 3500

**EDIT#1:**

This macro appears to do what you want:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, AB As Range

    Set A = Range("A1:A5000")
    Set B = Range("B1:B5000")
    Set AB = Union(A, B)

    A.Formula = "=row()"
    B.Formula = "=rand()"
    AB.Value = AB.Value

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=B, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange AB
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I assign this function using excel vba

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: excellent effort, but I am a touch worried that you are producing free work for someone who has demonstrated no effort at all, and may come back expecting more free work at another time.

Comment: @halfer Usually what I produce is a small fragment of a real application.  The Questioner must supply the rest!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub kTest()

Dim k, kk, kkk(), dic As Object, i As Long, t
Dim r As Long, j As Long, n As Long, p As Long
Dim ls As String

With Sheets("Summary").Range("XFA6")

        If Not IsDate(.Value) Then
           MsgBox "No date"
        Exit Sub
        ElseIf .Value < Date Then
            MsgBox "MIS"
        Exit Sub

        Else
        End If

    End With

ls = Worksheets("Summary").Range("E14").Value

Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
dic.comparemode = 1

With Worksheets("Source")
k = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value2
End With

For i = 2 To UBound(k, 1)
If Len(k(i, 1)) Then
t = dic.Item(k(i, 1))
If IsEmpty(t) Then
dic.Item(k(i, 1)) = Array(1, i)
Else
t(0) = t(0) + 1
t(1) = t(1) & "|" & i
dic.Item(k(i, 1)) = t
End If
End If
Next

kk = Array(dic.keys, dic.items)
ReDim kkk(1 To UBound(k, 1), 1 To UBound(k, 2))

For i = 0 To UBound(kk(0))
p = kk(1)(i)(0) * ls
t = Split(kk(1)(i)(1), "|")
dic.RemoveAll
j = 1
Do While j <= p
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(t) + 1) - 1
If Not dic.exists(r) Then
dic.Item(r) = Empty
n = n + 1
kkk(n, 1) = k(t(r), 1)
kkk(n, 2) = k(t(r), 2)

j = j + 1
End If
Loop
Next

If n Then
With Worksheets("Audit")
.[A1].CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
.[a2].Resize(n, 2).Value = kkk
End With
End If
End Sub
```